# Getting feature ids in a layer shown in map canvas extent with PyQGIS in QGIS3?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I am looking for a programmatic way to get all feature ids in a layer shown in the current map canvas extent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using this snippet

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
request = QgsFeatureRequest(iface.mapCanvas().extent())
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.ExactIntersect)
for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
  print (f.id())
```

This feature request will only use features that intersect canvas
view. Found [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Create-memory-layer-containing-only-features-visible-in-current-canvas-extent-td5303218.html)

Answer (score 4):

I actually found the solution myself:

```
for feature in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures(iface.mapCanvas().extent()):
    print(feature.id())
```